# Remap Meta key on Ubuntu terminal

Tags: ssh, remapping

I log into a remote machine through ssh and using emacs as my main editor over there. Since I am on Mac the `Meta` key is mapped to <kbd>ESC</kbd>.

How do I remap it to <kbd>⌥</kbd> key?

Comment: Try [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap)

Comment: @j-money but isn't `xmodmap` only for apps running under `X11`?